# Passive Voltage Divider attenuator design technique

Tags: resistors, attenuator

I want to build a passive attenuator which will attenuate an input signal. I want the to have 12 steps, starting with no attenuation and with each subsequent step having a 0.5dB attenuation (so down to -5.5dB). I will use a 12 way 2 pole rotary switch.

Because this is a passive attenuator the input voltage is unimportant, so for ease of calculation I will assume this will be 1V.

My work so far: I decided to have 13 resistors in a simple resistor divider configuration. I have worked out the percentage of Vin I wish to appear at each point. So 100% for the first point (direct connection, Vout = 1 V), 94.4% for the second point (Vout = 0.944 V), 89.13% for the third (Vout = 0.8913 V) and running down accordingly.

I was opting for 13 resistors to that the point under R12 will be 50% of Vin therefore R13 will equal the sum of R's 1-12

My question is: How I calculate the values of the resistors required because there are so many of them?

Do I just pick a value for Rtotal and work them all out from that, or can I formulate this mathematically and perhaps write some code to do this for me. Is there a way of exploiting the common resistor values to my advantage?

Comment: I thought of a way I might go about it. Because I know the voltage required at each point, can I consider the problem in smaller sets. So for the first set. I have 1V Vin and 0.8913V Vout, now I just calculate R1 and R2, then for the next one I have Vin = 1V and Vout = 0.8414V and a divider of (R1+R2) and R3. ??

Comment: The signal is being used to drive an amplifier and, as such, is very high impedance.

Comment: How are you selecting which resistors are in the circuit?  Are you using manual switches, or is this something that needs to be controlled electronically?  If so, have you considered an [EEPOT like this one](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/11195c.pdf) (just an example).

Comment: I was going to use a 12 way 2 pole switch, to manually switch in the resistors. So Pos1 - No resistance, Pos2 - R1, Pos3 - R1+R2 etc.

Comment: I had considered a digital pot but I have no control signal to drive it, This just just a passive black box.

Comment: This method of considering 2 resistors at a time does seem to work. In the end all the resistors will be defined by R1. So I can just pick a value for R1 and the rest will be defined.

Comment: Sounds like an excel problem to me.

Comment: That's an excellent idea Andy, I was just thinking this was going to take some time by hand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make life a bit easier use the switch wiper connected to the first resistor and the other switch contacts to individual resistors that connect to ground. Only one resistor gets grounded therefore there is no interdependence: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgg0Bq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, I had imagined that the signal in would go to the first contact, then R1 goes across the first and second contact R2 across the second and third etc, and the twelfth goes to ground, and the wiper as the output.

Comment: I can't imagine a configuration where there is interindependence... I'd go with your configuration because you can actually have a 0dB attenuation, but that's another story.

Comment: I actually think I see what you mean Andy, Do you mean that the signal would go into the wiper then each contact has a grounded resistor and all the contacts are connected to the output. So each selection only uses 2 resistors, removing the interdependence. ? ??

Comment: @TimMottram See the circuit I added. I've shown individual switches because that's all the circuit editor allows. You can do it this way or the "series" method you allude to.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that is what I was getting at in my last comment, I think this will produce a much better result. Thank you for you time.

Comment: @TimMottram - Yeah, This is a far better configuration for use with the rotary switch since it is possible to compute each resistor pair separately. Note that you can also invert the shown circuit where the input signal drives into a whole series of "upper" resistors and the rotary switch selects only one of them to voltage divide with a single "lower" resistor.

Comment: Ok, any advice as to the value to choose for the single upper (or lower) resistor? I want to keep it as simple as possible, that's what I meant about exploiting common resistor values.

Comment: @TimMottram The single upper resistor (on the highest attenuation setting of say 6dB) represents half the input resistance to the attenuator. Go as low as you dare so as to not introduce unreasonable amounts of resistor noise (boltzmanns constant etc..). How low can your input impedance be without excessively loading your input?

Comment: Well, I am using it to drive an amplifier, which has an input resistance of 4M Ohms - this cannot be changed. I just wanted to pick a resistor which worked well with other values so I don't need to series/parallel them to get the desired drop. What did you mean about "How low can your input impedance be without excessively loading your input?"

Comment: No, I'm **not** talking about what the voltage divider output feeds into - I'm talking about what signal feeds into the voltage divider and ensuring that the "load" presented by the voltage divider is not too low to cause problems for the signal you are feeding in.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. The output from the pre-amplifier is low impedance, 50 Ohm I think. So I can go fairly low I think.

Comment: I probably wouldn't go too low - maybe make the upper resistor between 1kohm and 10kohm - how about 3k3 - that's logarithmically about half way. You don't want to excessively load your pre-amp but only you can tell how much.

Comment: Ok, thanks Andy, I'll use that value and see what I get.